# Within Ansible Automation Platform, getting '/path/to/directory' does not exist, when it does indeed

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have a playbook scheduled via Ansible Automation Platform that gets all of the files within a directory. Below is an excerpt:

```yaml
- name: Find Backup Files to Move 
  find:
    paths: /path/to/directory 
    recurse: no 
    excludes: 'test-file.tar.gz' 
  delegate_to: localhost 
  register: testfiles
```

This playbook keeps failing with the following message:

```
[WARNING]: Skipped '/path/to/directory' path due to this access issue:
6
'/path/to/directory' is not a directory
```

The directory certainly does exist, and it is not empty. Below is the output from an `ll` command on `/path/to/directory`:

```
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx 98358 Dec  6 00:00 test-file-2022-backup-12-06-00:00:06.tar.gz
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 awx awx    80 Dec  6 00:00 test-file-latest.tar.gz -> /path/to/directory/test-file-backup-2022-12-06-00:00:06.tar.gz
```

What can I do to troubleshoot this further? It's not clear to me that this is a permission issue.

Below is the output from `ls -alZ /path`:

```
total 4
drwxr-x---.  4 awx  awx  unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0      62 Dec  5 23:12 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0            244 Dec  5 23:11 ..
drwxr-x---.  7 awx  awx  unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0  154 Dec  6 10:00 dir1
drwxr-x---.  2 awx  awx  unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0    4096 Dec  6 10:00 to
```

Below is the output from `ls -alZ /path/to/directory`:

```
drwxr-x---. 2 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0   4096 Dec  6 10:00 .
drwxr-x---. 4 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0     62 Dec  5 23:12 ..
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0  98358 Dec  6 00:00 test-file-backup-2022-12-06-00:00:06.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 105073 Dec  6 02:00 test-file-backup-2022-12-06-02:00:05.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 105066 Dec  6 04:00 test-file-backup-2022-12-06-04:00:05.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 105070 Dec  6 06:00 test-file-backup-2022-12-06-06:00:05.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 105068 Dec  6 08:00 test-file-backup-2022-12-06-08:00:05.tar.gz
-rwxr-x---. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 107031 Dec  6 10:00 test-file-backup-2022-12-06-10:00:05.tar.gz
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 awx awx unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0     80 Dec  6 10:00 test-file-backup-latest.tar.gz -> /path/to/directory/test-file-backup-2022-12-06-10:00:05.tar.gz
```

Below is the output from `ls -ld /path/`

```
drwxr-x---. 4 awx awx 62 Dec  5 23:12 /path/
```

I've tried to follow the example from @U88OD and below is the output I received:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show environment] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
  "msg": [
    "root",
    {
      "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING": "False",
      "RUNNER_ONLY_FAILED_EVENTS": "False",
      "ANSIBLE_PARAMIKO_RECORD_HOST_KEYS": "False",
      "PKGMGR_OPTS": "--nodocs --setopt=install_weak_deps=0 --setopt=rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms.excludepkgs=ansible-core",
      "_": "/usr/bin/python3.9",
      "AWX_ISOLATED_DATA_DIR": "/runner/artifacts/15",
      "HOSTNAME": "87098dfce111",
      "MAX_EVENT_RES": "700000",
      "AWX_HOST": "https://FQDN",
      "ANSIBLE_UNSAFE_WRITES": "1",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Red Hat Ansible Automation Platform Supported Execution Environment",
      "container": "oci",
      "INVENTORY_ID": "2",
      "PROJECT_REVISION": "",
      "ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH_DIR": "/runner/cp",
      "AWX_PRIVATE_DATA_DIR": "/tmp/awx_15_7u3ff0s7",
      "PWD": "/runner/project",
      "HOME": "/home/runner",
      "LC_CTYPE": "C.UTF-8",
      "ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED": "False",
      "ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH": "/runner/requirements_roles:~/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles",
      "ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK": "awx_display",
      "ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_UNPARSED_FAILED": "True",
      "ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS": "/runner/requirements_collections:~/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections",
      "TERM": "xterm",
      "RUNNER_OMIT_EVENTS": "False",
      "JOB_ID": "15",
      "ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR": "True",
      "SHLVL": "2",
      "ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS": "/runner/artifacts/15/callback",
      "PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    },
    [
      "/runner/inventory/hosts"
    ],
    "Ansible Backup",
    15,
    "manual"
  ],
  "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": null,
  "changed": false
}

[WARNING]: Skipped '/tmp/ansible_backups/' path due to this access issue:
'/tmp/ansible_backups/' is not a directory
ok: [localhost]
TASK [Show result] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 0,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [],
        "matched": 0,
        "msg": "Not all paths examined, check warnings for details",
        "skipped_paths": {
            "/tmp/ansible_backups/": "'/tmp/ansible_backups/' is not a directory"
        },
        "warnings": [
            "Skipped '/tmp/ansible_backups/' path due to this access issue: '/tmp/ansible_backups/' is not a directory\n"
        ]
    }
}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

There appears to be something seriously wrong because Ansible cannot find any local directories!

Comment: it is not clear from your debugging information if that directory really exists. More over - if the command you used to check the content was effectively targeting the given directory - it is not clear either if you checked that on localhost or on the target server. And we have no idea which is the target server anyway. In other words, please [edit] your question and add a [mre].

Comment: Note: [paths are checked with `os.path.isdir`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1424484be0e1b9a1d1e7e1849ae1a5e2a19d612c/lib/ansible/modules/find.py#L459). This function might return false if the target dir is inside a path for which the user does not have permission on a lower dir. As a simple test you can try `sudo mkdir /root/A; python -c "import os; print(os.path.isdir('/root')); print(os.path.isdir('/root/A'))"; sudo rmdir /root/A`

Comment: @Zeitounator - The directory is local (i.e. on the Ansible node) which is why I'm using the `delegate_to: localhost` argument. It does indeed exist.  I've tried your script, other than switching it to `python3`, it worked perfectly - two lines of "True".

Comment: Currently are shown only files which are within the directory, but not the access rights for the directory itself. Can you also show the output of `ls -alZ /path && ls -alZ /path/to?

Comment: @U880D I've edited the question to include those commands. Thanks for offering your help.

Comment: The last one to check is `ls -ld /path` (although `'.'` in your `ls /path` output is probably enough). Note that `namei -om /path/to/directory` can be helpfull to get this information in one shot. Meanwhile, are you running all this on your local machine or inside the docker container running awx (where the files need to exist if you want to run the playbook there targeting localhost - i.e. the awx container...)?

Comment: If my above comment was not clear enough, can you see the directory when running `docker exec -it <your_awx_container> ls -l /path/to/directory`?

Comment: @Zeitounator - I am not running Ansible Automation Platform in Docker. Below is what I am getting when trying to run your command `-bash: docker: command not found`

Comment: @Zeitounator - for clarity, I installed Ansible Automation Hub using the following instructions: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ansible_automation_platform/2.0-ea/html/red_hat_ansible_automation_platform_installation_guide/single-machine-scenario

Comment: Because it is totally unclear for me what is your use case and what you try to achieve, I've provided a partial answer which reproduce your observation. Maybe you can give more details about "Backup Files to Move" and if it is regarding backup of the drop in application database (PostgreSQL).

Comment: According the given output the execution was done by [Ansible Runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This is something I haven't tested or worked with yet. Nevertheless "_There appears to be something seriously wrong because Ansible cannot find any local directories!_" I don't think there is something wrong with the behavior. But with the approach of trying to access "local" directories.

Comment: As @Zeitounator already mentioned to check for container environment, the output "`"HOSTNAME": "87098dfce111",...,"container": "oci"`" indicates for me that it is running within a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the @U880D is correct. This playbook is running within a container, and that doesn’t have access to the underlying host file system. This is a new change in Ansible Automation Platform 2. More details can be found here:

https://www.ansible.com/blog/when-localhost-isnt-what-it-seems-in-red-hat-ansible-automation-platform-2

In my use case an external process is running a backup job in Ansible and I want to copy the files to a NFS.

For anyone else that is trying to run this, I ended up creating a bash script and dropping it in `/etc/cron.hourly`. That bash script includes backing up Tower and copying the files from the backup folder to remote storage. I'm also deleting past backups older 14 days. Below is the bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#       Switch to the Ansible backup folder.
cd /tower_backup/ansible-tower-backup-scripts/;

#       Run the Ansible Backup
./setup.sh -e 'backup_dest=/tmp/ansible_backups/' -b > /dev/null

#       Copy all of the files in this folder over to remote storage.
cp -n /tmp/ansible_backups/*.tar.gz /mnt/ansible_backups/

#       Delete remote backups older than 14 days.
find /mnt/ansible_backups -mtime +14 -delete;

#       Delete local backups older than 2 days.
find /tmp/ansible_backups -type f -mtime +2 -delete;
```

**Remember to mount the NFS before you create the cron job otherwise, your files will not be copied over to remote storage.**

Answer (score 0):

> *What can I do to troubleshoot this further? It's not clear to me that this is a permission issue.*

According your description I understand that you like to do an investigation or debugging on your Control Node(s) (only). To do so, you may have a look into the following minimal test playbook.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show environment
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ ansible_user }}"
        - "{{ ansible_env }}"
        - "{{ ansible_inventory_sources }}"
        - "{{ tower_job_template_name }}"
        - "{{ tower_job_id }}"
        - "{{ tower_job_launch_type }}"

  - name: Find available files
    find:
      paths: ['/tmp/ansible/', '/home/awx/']
      recurse: yes
      file_type: directory
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

The following directories are available and accessible

```bash
$ ls -alZ /home/ | grep awx
drwx------. awx  awx   unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 awx
$ ls -alZ /tmp/ansible/ | tail -2
drwxrwxr-x. user users unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 facts_cache
```

Executing the playbook (on a RHEL 7.9.x system, no container environment, Ansible Engine 2.9.27, Python 2.7.5, Ansible Tower 3.7.x, Python 3.6) will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show environment] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "root", 
        {
            "ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS": "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awx/plugins/callback:/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/callbacks", 
            "ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS": "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd/requirements_collections:~/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections", 
            "ANSIBLE_FACT_CACHE_TIMEOUT": "0", 
...
            "ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH": "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd/requirements_roles:./:~/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles", 
            "ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH_DIR": "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd/cp", 
            "ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK": "awx_display", 
            "ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible", 
            "AWX_HOST": "https://awx.example.com", 
            "AWX_ISOLATED_DATA_DIR": "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd/artifacts/1234", 
            "AWX_PRIVATE_DATA_DIR": "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd", 
...
            "HOME": "/var/lib/awx", 
            "INVENTORY_ID": "1", 
...
            "JOB_ID": "1234", 
...
            "PATH": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible/bin:/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/bin:/opt/rh/rh-postgresql10/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", 
...
            "PROJECT_REVISION": "abcdefg...0123456...tuvwxyz", 
            "PROOT_TMP_DIR": "/tmp", 
            "PWD": "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd/project/localhost", 
            "PYTHONPATH": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awx/lib:/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/callbacks", 
            "RUNNER_OMIT_EVENTS": "False", 
            "RUNNER_ONLY_FAILED_EVENTS": "False", 
...
            "SHLVL": "2", 
            "SUPERVISOR_ENABLED": "1", 
            "SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME": "tower-processes", 
            "SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME": "awx-dispatcher", 
            "SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL": "unix:///var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock", 
            "TZ": "UTC", 
            "USER": "awx", 
            "VIRTUAL_ENV": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible", 
            "_": "/usr/bin/python2"
        }, 
        [
            "/tmp/awx_1234_abcd/tmp1234abcd"
        ], 
        "localhost - Debug execution environment", 
        1234, 
        "manual"
    ]
}
TASK [Find available files] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost]
TASK [Show result] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false, 
        "examined": 2, 
        "failed": false, 
        "files": [
            {
...
                "path": "/tmp/ansible/facts_cache", 
                "pw_name": "awx", 
...
            }
        ], 
        "matched": 1, 
        "msg": "/home/awx/ was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"
    }
}
```

From the output you can see that the directory under `/tmp/` can be accessed but under `/home/` not.

Please take note of in especially of

```yaml
"ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible"
"HOME": "/var/lib/awx"
"PROOT_TMP_DIR": "/tmp"
"USER": "awx"
"VIRTUAL_ENV": "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible"
```

and others.

**Summary**

For me this seems to be the expected behavior.

**How to proceed further?**

Change your path to under `/tmp/awx/` or `/var/lib/awx` and do further testing.

Comment: I've tried to follow your example, and below is what I get.